# TextView values in fragment not being cleared

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with 2 fragments. Fragment A has TextViews used as search fields. Fragment B shows the results based on the search.

I have button in my actionbar to clear the search fields. This button is for the activity and can be clicked from both fragments.

This is the code for the action button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //Delete
    if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
        if (fragmentA != null) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragmentA.clearAll();
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

With the above code, I return back to the first fragment (it's not added to the backstack). However the textviews are not cleared.

The `clearAll` method is called correctly because I'm also clearing properties of a custom object. However, the text in the textviews stay there. I have to click the button a second time (when fragment A is displayed) so that the text is cleared.

This is the method:

```
public void clearAll() {
    searchClass.name = "";
    searchClass.surname = "";

    tvName.setText(null);
    tvSurname.setText(null);
}
```

I'm setting `null` and not "" so that the hints should be displayed again.

What am I missing? Could it be that the fragment is is not shown so its view is still not available?

Comment: use "" instead of null

Comment: @AnandSavjani I had that before. It doesn't work either.

Comment: use clearAll method in onResume() method

Comment: use tvName.setHint("");

Comment: @AnandSavjani I only want to clear the text when the user clicks on delete. If the user goes back to the first fragment, the text should still be displayed.

Comment: its text or hint ? First clear about it

Comment: @AnandSavjani If I do setText(null), the hint will be re-displayed automatically. Either way, the text is never getting clearing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81243/discussion-between-anand-savjani-and-ivan-mark-debono).

Comment: Whether the fragmentA instance remains same when you call the clearAll method?

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```
tvName.setText("");
tvSurname.setText("");
```

**Instead of this**

```
tvName.setText(null);
tvSurname.setText(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
public void clearAll() {
    searchClass.name = "";
    searchClass.surname = "";

    tvName.setText("");
    tvSurname.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work the following changes were done:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //Delete
    if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
        if (fragmentA != null) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

            if (currentFragment == fragmentA ) {
                fragmentA.clearAllImmediate();
            }
            else {
                fragmentA.clearAll();
            }
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And then in the fragment itself:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (needToClear) {
        clearAllImmediate();
        needToClear = false;
    }
}

public void clearAll() {
    needToClear = true;
}

public void clearAllImmediate() {
    searchClass.name = "";
    searchClass.surname = "";

    tvName.setText(null);
    tvSurname.setText(null);
}
```